# I can't figure out why this code in my APCS multiple choice book returns 19

Tags: java

So here is the method and the question:

```
public static int mystery(int n) {
   if (Math.sqrt(n) > n/4) {
      return n;
   } else {
      return mystery(n-1);
   }
}
```

What value is returned as a result of the call `mystery(21)`?

The correct answer is 19 and I got that answer when I put the code into my compiler, but I haven't figured out why that is the correct answer.

Comment: Time to debug and validate.  In your method, print the value of `Math.sqrt(n)` to the output.  And of `n/4`.  And of `n-1`.  What do they all print?  This debugging may indeed lead to *other* questions (such as what "integer division" means).  But currently you have exactly the tools you need at your disposal to answer the question you're asking at this time... You can step through the code in a debugger, observe runtime values, output useful information, and observe exactly what the code is doing.

Comment: Integer division for the loss.

Comment: Compute the square root of each number and 1/4th of each number, and establish which value of `n` is such that sqrt(n) > n/4.  This is something that should ideally be done on a whiteboard, or with pen and paper.

Comment: @TheHeadRush:  `n` was already an integer.  You don't divide any of the floating point values.

Comment: Compare `sqrt(n)` to `n/4` where `n` is 20, and then 19. Notice the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Math.sqrt(double a);
```

Returns a double.

```
(Any Double) / (Any Integer)
```

Returns a integer [rounding down], whereas

```
(Any Double) / (Any Double)
```

Returns a double.

**Question 1:**

```
Math.sqrt(21) == 4.58257569496;
21 / 4 == 5;
Math.sqrt(21) < 21 / 4;

//(Then it returns Mystery(n-1))
Math.sqrt(20) == 4.472135955;
20 / 4 == 5;
Math.sqrt(20) < 20 / 4;

//Then it returns Mystery(n-1)
Math.sqrt(19) == 4.35889894354;
19 / 4 == 4;
Math.sqrt(19) > 19 / 4;

returns 19;
```

**Question 2:**

```
Math.sqrt(19) == 4.35889894354.
19 / 4 == 4 
//It would be 4.75, **but** java rounds down to the nearest Integer, but it ALWAYS rounds down.
//To stop this, the condition Math.sqrt(n) > n/4;
//Would become                Math.sqrt(n) > n/4.0;
```